# Faraday Cage - Wavelength and hole size

Tags: voltage, current, electromagnetism, microwave, faraday-cage

I read about the faraday cages and understood that the size of the holes should be very small than the wavelength of the signal for effective shielding.

But I am really confused due to the illustrations of the high and low wavelength signals.

Like, if there is a hole, of a certain size, doesn't matter about the frequency of the signal, the signals (assume a sine wave) with low amplitude , comparable to the size of the hole, will pass through and signals will amplitude higher than the size of the hole, will be blocked. But I know this is wrong. But due to the illustrations , I can think of only the amplitude to be the blocking factor.

Can someone provide an illustration as the why the wavelength of the signal is the limiting factor and not frequency or amplitude.

Comment: But the wavelength and frequency are related: \$\lambda=\frac{c}{v}\$, where \$\lambda\$ is the wavelenght, \$c\$ is the speed of light, and \$v\$ is the frequency. Amplitude doesn't matter much because, so long as the massive sea of electrons in the metal are free to move about and respond, they can respond in kind.

Comment: Sorry, yes. But all the illustrations I have seen confuses me. How does the wavelength and the frequency of a signal will determine the size of the holes? Like, if the amplitude of the signal is high, won't it hit the edges of the holes and get cut off?

Comment: Do remember that amplitude is not measured in meters. This is an electromagnetic wave we're talking about, not a water wave.

Comment: Yes, but still I am not clear with this concept. All these illustrations have not been clear for me. It would be great if I could get some illustrations explaining the actual concept.

Comment: @Newbie Yes, the holes are a problem for electrons. That's why the frequency determines the worst case hole size. If the frequency is slow enough that the electrons can migrate around the holes in time, then it works okay. If the frequency is too fast, and the electrons can't move correctly fast enough because the hole is in the way, then not so good for the shielding.

Comment: Hi Newbie.   The problem here is your visualization of an electromagnetic wave.  You are interpreting it in your head as if the amplitude were a 3D measure -  In other words, that it has "height".  It does not have a measurable height, so it has no relation to the physical size of the hole.   That's not how it works.  It's a voltage potential that travels through space.  It's measured in volts/meter to define the field strength, not it's height in meters or inches or whatever.   This is not an easy to thing to visualize but keep working at it and eventually it will click in your head.

Comment: The wavelength is important and is critical in the effect of the hole.  And again it's not quite what you're thinking.  The wave does not pass through the hole.  The wave is captured by the metal case, and is then re-emitted by the hole - it acts as a 'slot antenna'.   The efficiency of an antenna is related to the relative physical size of the antenna to the wavelength of the E-wave.  If the hole is as big as, or greater than, about maybe 1/20 a wavelength, it will be an efficient enough antenna.  It will APPEAR as if the wave passes through the hole, but that's not quite what's occurring.

Comment: @KyleB , thank you very much for your clarification. yes, I am finding it difficult to visualize the concept. Let me try to understand it

Comment: @Newbie Here is a more accurate visualisation of electromagnetic fields: http://www.met.rdg.ac.uk/clouds/maxwell/microwave_oven.html

Comment: The classical illustration of a sine wave in a 2D drawing is a bit misleading. Instead of a wave going up and down in altitude, imagine points of space pulsing in intensity / 'color'.

Comment: @DamienD, thank you very much for the link. I will look and try to understand

Answer (score 1):

The detailed analysis of this question gets complicated real fast, based on the size, shape, and pattern of apertures on shielding. And an exact answer may require field simulations. An excellent coverage of this topic is in "Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering" by Henry Ott, chapter Shielding, section Apertures.

Amplitude of the signal to be contained has little to do with the effectiveness of the shielding. The more energy the signal has (the higher the amplitude), the more of it escapes. DO NOT think about this as waves propagating on the surface of water, and as long as the waves are small they fit through a small opening.
Relationship between wavelength and frequency are determined by the medium in which electromagnetic waves propagate, and they are inversely proportional. In the same medium, such as air, the higher the frequency, the shorter the wavelength, and it is the wavelength that determines what fits through a hole and what doesn't.

Things to remember:

1. An aperture (slot or opening) in shielding can be conceptually thought of as an antenna. E.g. the spectral emission properties of a thin, 10mm long slot are similar to a 10mm long stub antenna, except the magnetic and electric fields are swapped, which in the near field results to a 90 degree shift in the phase of radiation
   emitted.
2. The higher the frequency the smaller the wavelength, and more energy can leak through an aperture in your EMI shield. Essentially the aperture acts as a high-pass filter. The principal factor that determines the cutoff frequency is the maximum linear length of a slot.
3. The shielding effectiveness (S) in dB is equal to $$
   S = 20 \log \frac{\lambda}{2l} $$ where \$\lambda\$ is the wavelength, and \$l\$ is the maximum linear dimension of the aperture. E.g. a 6" (150mm) slot will suppress a 100MHz signal 20dB. The same aperture will be less and less effective against higher harmonics, but will leak only 1% of energy of a signal at 10MHz. A 15 mm (0.6") diameter hole will suppress a 1GHz signal by 20dB, 100MHz by 40dB.

If you are forced to punch holes on an enclosure to facilitate airflow, use small, circular holes in a honeycomb pattern.